# Show set is a basis - complex sequences which are eventually zero

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $c_{00}$ be the subspace of all sequences of complex numbers that are "eventually zero". i.e. for an element $x \in c_{00}$, $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n =0,  \forall n\ge n$.

Let {$e_i$}$_{i \in \mathbb N}$ be the set where $e_i$ is the sequence in $c_{00}$ given by $(e_i)_n= {1,  n=i}$ and $(e_i)_n= {0, n \neq i}$.

Show that $({e_i})_{i \in \mathbb N}$ is a basis for $c_{00}$.

So I need to show it's linearly independent and that it spans $c_{00}$. I am not sure how to go about proving it spans. What makes it confusing is that it's an infinite set...

Comment: Take any sequence $x \in c_{00}$. How can you use that $x_n = 0$ for all large enough $n$?

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, the sequence will go to zero. But I don't see how I can use that for span.

Comment: Not "will go to zero". _Is zero_.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it will equal zero. I know that $(e_i)$ is zero in all position except the $ith$, but the whole idea of it spanning $c_{00}$ remains unclear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\{e_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ spans $c_{00}$, you must show that each $x \in c_{00}$ can be written as a linear combination of a finite number of the $e_i$.

Now, if we consider an arbitrary finite linear combination of $e_i$s, say

$$y = \sum_{i=0}^N \lambda_i \cdot e_i,$$

what will be the $k$-th component of $y$?

Finding the answer to this question will show how to write a given $x \in c_{00}$ as a finite linear combination of the $e_i$.